# delete nodes from a graph in for loop

Tags: python, igraph

I'm using **igraph-python**.
I'm trying to solve a problem called the longest induced path, I'm choosing, in the beginning, a random node , find it's neighbors then choose one from the neighbors based on the value of closeness centrality, delete the others and so on
My code is the following

```
from random import randint
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from igraph import *
from numpy import random
def maximum(a, n):
maxpos = a.index ( max ( a ) )
return maxpos

G = Graph ()
G.add_vertices(5)
G.add_edges([(0, 1), (0, 2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4)])

n = G.vcount()
first = random.randint(n)
neigh = G.neighbors(first)
clos = G.closeness(vertices=neigh)
induced_path = first
G.delete_vertices(first)
while len(neigh) > 0:
     pos = maximum(clos, len(clos))
     j= neigh[pos]
     np.append(induced_path,j)
     print(induced_path)
     neigh = np.setdiff1d(neigh,j)
     G.delete_vertices(neigh)
     neigh = G.neighbors(j)
     clos = G.closeness(vertices=neigh)
     G.delete_vertices(j)
     print(len(induced_path))
```

when I'm running this code python giving me this error:

```
Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

also there is a problem in the line of finding the neighbours of j as follows:

```
cannot get neighbors, Invalid vertex id
```

Traceback:

```
File "E:/inducedpath/indu.py", line 30, in <module> G.delete_vertices(neigh) igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at c:\projects\python-igraph\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.8.0-msvc\src\iterators.c:764: Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Comment: can you please share the whole traceback so we can see which line the error occurs.

Comment: @zypro    File "E:/inducedpath/indu.py", line 31, in <module>
    neigh = G.neighbors (j)
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at c:\projects\python-igraph\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.8.0-msvc\src\type_indexededgelist.c:747: cannot get neighbors, Invalid vertex id

Comment: @zypro   File "E:/inducedpath/indu.py", line 30, in <module>
    G.delete_vertices(neigh)
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at c:\projects\python-igraph\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.8.0-msvc\src\iterators.c:764: Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id

Comment: and you have the whitespace above behind `G.delete_vertices` also like that in your code ?! That will be an issue too.  (also behind `G.neighbors`)

Comment: @zypro sorry I didn't get your question, do you mean the spaces between G.delete_vertices and  (neigh)??? if you mean this no it's in my code like this G.delete_vertices(neigh)  neigh=G.neighbors(j)

Comment: Have a look at this mailinglist: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2010-06/msg00050.html . Maybe you need to use a `-1` when accessing an index.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#delete_vertices) you should't use the label of the vertex but the id(s).

Have a look at the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332220/python-igraph-delete-vertices-from-a-graph).

For multiple ids:

```
to_delete_ids = [x.index for x in G.vs]
G.delete_vertices(to_delete_ids)
```

For a single vertex:
`G.delete_vertices(x.index)`

Comment: thank you for your reply, but still do I need to do the same everywhere for example if I want to find the neighbors of vertex should I do it, in the same way,         neigh = G.neighbors (x.index) ????

Comment: I mean how I can reserve the index of the vertex for everything in my work, neighbors, vertices to delete, assign vertex to a variable, should I do the same ???

Comment: Update your question and add your code then I might help you ;-)

Comment: can you please check it now :)